# Multiple MySQLi prepared UPDATE statement in a SELECT

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

I have two or more statements on one page of my site. And it does not work properly.
The first code is like that:

```
$query = "SELECT gpname FROM guineapigs WHERE fbid=?";
if ($statement = $mysqli->prepare($query)) {

$statement->bind_param('s', $_SESSION[FBID]);

$statement->execute();

$statement->bind_result($gpname);

while($statement->fetch()) {
  echo $gpname;
}
}

$statement->close();
```

The problem is when I try to add the second code to it:

```
if($_GET[buy]=='ch'){
$statement = $mysqli->prepare("UPDATE users SET `money` = `money`+ 22000 WHERE gpname=?");
$statement->bind_param('s', $gpname);
$results = $statement->execute();
header( "Location: /test.php?bsuccess=ch" );
}

if($_GET[bsuccess]=='ch'){
echo "Successfully added 22000 money..";
}
```

My code looks like this, but not working:

```
$query = "SELECT gpname FROM guineapigs WHERE fbid=?";
if ($statement = $mysqli->prepare($query)) {

$statement->bind_param('s', $_SESSION[FBID]);

$statement->execute();

$statement->bind_result($gpname);

while($statement->fetch()) {
      if($_GET[buy]=='ch'){
$statement2 = $mysqli->prepare("UPDATE users SET `money` = `money`+ 22000 WHERE gpname=?");
$statement2->bind_param('s', $gpname);
$statement2->execute();
header( "Location: /test.php?bsuccess=ch" );
}

if($_GET[bsuccess]=='ch'){
echo "Successfully added 22000 money..";
}
}
}

$statement->close();
```

What am I doing wrong? I want to add even more UPDATE querys after selecting.

Comment: Debug `$gpname` and make sure it's what you're expecting it to be

Comment: 1) https://php.net/manual/en/function.error-reporting.php 2)  http://php.net/mysqli_error - Run those in there then update your post to contain what the errors are, if any.

Comment: Why don't you simply `UPDATE users JOIN guineapigs USING (gpname) SET users.money = users.money + 22000 WHERE guineapigs.fbid = ?`?

Comment: These are the errors: Notice: Undefined property: mysqli::$mysqliect_error in /srv/disk2/2441089/www/guineapignursery.ml/dbtest.php on line 7

Fatal error: Call to a member function bind_param() on boolean in /srv/disk2/2441089/www/guineapignursery.ml/test.php on line 22

Comment: eggyal, I will try that just I have many more tables in my database to connect with :S

Comment: @krisz44g The first error is because you typed something wrong. It should be `$mysqli->error` but you wrote `$mysqli->mysqliect_error`.

Comment: The funny thing is that nothing in that row from where this error comes.. :( And the second? :S

Comment: The purpose why I need this solution so much because I want to check that the database values higher or lower than a number and then I want to decide based on it. 1st version is that I add + money to the database, 2nd is that I don't add. And the values came from 2 different databases. So there are many if() and $_GET and others needed to get the value from this query... :/

Comment: Put your `prepare()` call outside of the loop.  Bind and execute inside the loop.

Comment: That you for all the answers, finally I found out what was the mistake. :')

Answer (score 0):

Ohh, I'm an idiot! That was the mistake: 
Instead of

```
while ($stmt1->fetch()){ 
};
```

needs only:

```
while ($stmt1->fetch());
```

Here's a working example with some development:

```
<?php 
ob_start();
session_start();

include_once 'dbtest.php';

mysqli_report(MYSQLI_REPORT_ERROR | MYSQLI_REPORT_STRICT);
try {
  $mysqli->autocommit(FALSE); //turn on transactions

  $stmt1 = $mysqli->prepare("SELECT fbname,fbemail FROM users WHERE fbid = ?");
  $stmt1->bind_param("s", $_SESSION['FBID']);
  $stmt1->execute();
  $stmt1->bind_result($fbname,$fbemail);
  while ($stmt1->fetch());

  $stmt2 = $mysqli->prepare("INSERT INTO test (name,email) VALUES (?, ?)");
  $stmt2->bind_param("ss", $fbname, $fbemail);
  $stmt2->execute();
  $stmt2->close();

  $stmt1->close();

  $mysqli->autocommit(TRUE); //turn off transactions + commit queued queries
} catch(Exception $e) {
  $mysqli->rollback(); //remove all queries from queue if error (undo)
  error_log($e);
}
?>
```

Thank you anyway!!

Comment: Note: You should move all of your `prepare()` statements OUTSIDE of the loop.